# Flutter How to List Array with multiple children from JSON

Tags: mysql, json, dart, flutter

i have a difficult time to parsing a value from json.
i would like to create a ListView Builder with expansion and have a children inside expansion.
i mean like below

[Sample i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XrEV.png)

but i don't how to parsing all children based on the type.
for detail sql table and query please check below :

```
[
{
    "ID_Type": "1",
    "Type": "Food",
    "Item": [
        {
            "SLU_Number": "3",
            "SLU_Name": "Food"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "ID_Type": "2",
    "Type": "Beverages",
    "Item": [
        {
            "SLU_Number": "1",
            "SLU_Name": "Non Alcohol"
        },
        {
            "SLU_Number": "2",
            "SLU_Name": "Alchohol"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

i watch some video and follow the suggestion and i create a new dart file with new class called ListType.dart

here the code

```
class Products {
  final ID_Type;
  final Name_Type;
  final Items;

  Products({
    this.ID_Type,
    this.Name_Type,
    this.Items,
  });

  factory Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Products(
      ID_Type: json["ID_Type"],
      Name_Type: json["Type"],
      Items: Item.fromJson(json["Item"]),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  final SLU_Number;
  final SLU_Name;

  Item({
    this.SLU_Number,
    this.SLU_Name,
  });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Item(
      SLU_Number: json["SLU_Number"],
      SLU_Name: json["SLU_Name"],
    );
  }
}
```

but since the video throw the value to list so i dont know to throw the json value to ListView.Builder.

here below how i usually throw to List View Builder

```
//------------------------------Start Syntax for List SLU
  final listslu = new List<ListSLU>();
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshlistslu =
      GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();


  Future<void> ListSLUs() async {
    listslu.clear();
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    try {
      final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.ListSLU);
      if (response.contentLength == 2) {
      } else {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        data.forEach((api) {
          final b = new ListSLU(
            api['ID_Type'].toString(),
            api['SLU_Number'].toString(),
            api['SLU_Name'].toString(),
          );
          listslu.add(b);
          print(api['SLU_Name'].toString());
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error List SLU :");
      print(e);
    }
  }
  //------------------------------End Syntax for List Type
```

here below i throw to body based on future async i created above

```
Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listslu.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,i){
                  final z = listslu[i];
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){

                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                          Text(z.SLU_Number +' - '+ z.SLU_Name),
                        ],
                      ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              )
          ),
```

please your advice.

Comment: Very blurry picture, code can be copy-pasted into gist.github.com or any other pastebin - much better than a screenshot.

Comment: please review my code

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to use `where()` on items to filter them, and then use `map()` to convert each row of json to `ListTile()`

```
ExpansionTile(
   ...
   children: jsonData
      .where((row) => row["ID_Type"] == listtypes[i].ID_Type)
      .map((row) =>
         ListTile(
            title: Text(row["SLU_Name"])
         )
      )
)
```

Comment: i have edit my thread. could you help me, i want all value from json result throw to Listview.builder.

Comment: Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432234/how-to-set-the-list-of-json-data-inside-list-in-the-listview-builder-in-flutter